# UWP Duration control

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

Is there a control I can use the same as the duration control that Microsoft use on their standard alarms & clocks app for their countdown timer?

I cannot find a control that can do this on the standard controls in visual studio and I cant find anything similar on the net either, can anybody help?

[image: Duration Control]

Comment: The default TimePicker control does not provide such functionality. You'll need to write your own UserControl.

Comment: Check out the TimeSpanPicker for windows phone, http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#source/Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Controls/ValuePicker/TimeSpanPicker/TimeSpanPicker.cs